# Is there any way how to reactivate email notifications for new messages on Facebook's Messenger?

Tags: email, notifications, facebook

I was getting email notifications for new messages on Facebook's Messenger. Then I installed Messenger Android app. Then I removed Android app. I would like to use Facebook and Messenger on web only. I would like to reactivate email notifications for new messages on Messenger, but in the Messenger's settings, there is only a setting for Desktop Notifications, which don't work for me. Is there any way how to activate email notifications?

On the main Facebook app there are many other notification settings, but not for new messages.

Comment: Haven't checked, but I think the mail notification setting might be on the main Facebook app instead.

Comment: On the main Facebook app there are many other notification settings, but not for new messages.